# Opening CHM files on Mac OS X Lion, says PowerPC applications are not supported

Tags: osx-lion, chm

I used to be able to open CHM files. Now when I try, I get a message saying:

> Can't open … because PowerPC applications are no longer supported

Is there anything free that I can use that will open CHM files on OS X Lion?

Comment: I wonder what app it's trying to open. Are these .chm files Microsoft "Compressed HTML" web archives? Is it trying to open some ancient version of MSIE/Mac 5.x that you've had around since way back in the day?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you've probably been using an old application that didn't come as Universal Binary or was ever compiled for Intel Macs. Since OS X Lion, you can't run applications that were compiled for PowerPC only.

A quick search found [CHM View](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/chm-view/id449814591?mt=12), a free tool to view CHM files. It's in the Apple Store, so that will work on an Intel Mac running OS X Lion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try the iChm, a Cocoa CHM reader for both Mac and iOS devices. Take a look at, http://www.robinlu.com/ichm